# Clojure's Fleet Templates: how to use "fleet-ns"?

Tags: templates, clojure

I'm working on a web app using Clojure, Ring, Composure, and Fleet.  I like the flexibility of Fleet and I find the syntax of its template files easy to read and intuitive. However, the documentation is sparse and I'm having difficulty understanding the use of macro, "fleet-ns" which produces namespaced functions for .fleet files in a directory tree.

In particular, the README.md file makes this statement about the production of these functions:

> — Several functions will be created for each file. E.g. file posts.html.fleet will 
>   produce 3 functions: posts, posts-html and posts-html-fleet.

I can't find any explanation of why there are three functions, what they each is used for, or what their differences are.

The examples I've found by search have been fragmentary, incomplete or obscured by other issues.

Overall my feeling is that the adoption of this excellently conceived package is being hampered by the lack of documentation.  I am inclined to improve if I can figure out a bit more about the way Fleet works.

Any help, pointers, or canonical examples appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed documentation is scarce. Maybe you can use enlive instead. There are plenty of examples available on the web.
You can also read (if you haven't already) the following:
http://cleancode.se/2011/01/04/getting-started-with-moustache-and-enlive.html
and a very nice paper by Glenn Vanderburg:
http://steve.vinoski.net/pdf/IC-Clojure_Templating_Libraries_Fleet_and_Enlive.pdf